# Manually plotting straight boundary line in Perceptron

Tags: r, plot, machine-learning

[The material belongs to the [Coursera Machine Learning course by Andrew Ng](https://www.coursera.org/learn/machine-learning)]

I got one of the exercises to work in R (I could have opted for Python - not essential to the question), using different methodology, and got the following plot with the boundary decision line on it:

[image]

The red points were admitted to a college, while the rest were not.

The question is not a how-to get the line on the plot, but rather why does the following line in the code adapted to R from the course materials works:

`y = c((-1/coefs[3]) * (coefs[2] * x + coefs[1]))`

So it is in reality asking about the math underpinning this command. The coefficients correspond to the logistic regression coefficients.

[Here is the dataset](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0Bwl-HpVJ_5PecGxuWk9vR1pzWUk), and here is the entire code:

```
dat = read.csv("perceptron.txt", header=F)
is.data.frame(dat)
colnames(dat) = c("test1","test2","y")
head(dat)

plot(test2 ~ test1, col = as.factor(y), pch = 20, data=dat)

fit = glm(y ~ test1 + test2, family = "binomial", data = dat)
coefs = coef(fit)
(x = c(min(dat[,1])-2,  max(dat[,1])+2))
(y = c((-1/coefs[3]) * (coefs[2] * x + coefs[1])))
lines(x, y)
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is actually quite easy:

The boundary is at:

```
0 = theta_0 + theta_1 x_1 + theta_2 x_2
```

Hence, since the plot is of `x_2` versus `x_1`, we choose two extreme points along `x_1` and calculate the expected `x_2` at the decision boundary:

```
x_2 = (- 1 / theta_2) * (theta_0 + theta_1 x_1)
```